# VisualForce Page redirects to Salesforce Core (Sales app) when Record Page button is clicked from Partner Community

Tags: visualforce, community, experience-cloud, setup

I'm facing the following issue while creating a new Experience Cloud Portal (Community):

**I've added a custom button on a Case Related List of an Account Record Page. The user profile has permission to the layout,objects, VisualForce Page. But While testing, logged as a partner community user, for some reason, when clicked, the i'm redirected to a login page, probably to salesforce sales app, what could be the reason?**

The custom button has the URL below as its content source.

{!URLFOR($Site.BaseUrl+'/apex/ATCL_LVFP008_DamagedArtefact?id='+Account.Id)}

ATCL_LVFP008_DamagedArtefact being the VisualForce Page.

[image: custom button setup]

I've also tried to set its content as a visualforce directly with no better results.

This VisualForce page is already marked as avaliable for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites,etc.

Comment: You need to change how the URL is built, using the other variants of [URLFOR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm).